# After formating date uisng moment.js, the output will be a string and not a datetime

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, format, momentjs

I am using moment.js to format time, but after formating, the output will result as a string,
I need the variable as a DateTime since I am using that variable to insert in the database, and insertion cannot be done successfully since the now variable is a string.

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment-timezone";
    
let now = moment().tz("Europe/Berlin").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    
console.log(typeof now); // STRING
```

Comment: You also need to format the date on server side, or in the sql query. There is no such datatype as date in js.

Comment: Dates are just a time value that is an offset from the ECMAScript epoch. The sole purpose of formatting is to produce a string timestamp (typically human readable), it has zero effect on the Date object that is being formatted.